# rails mysql2 error Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, centos

i want to deploy rails app on centOS, after installing all things needed, i got his error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

But i can create database and migrate.
I also can enter mysql console with current password. please help.

Comment: Did you make the necessary `database.yml` changes?

Comment: yes i did. with the correct username and password. i can do migrate but can't see my web page

Comment: Can you include your database.yml ?

Comment: This will likely be a problem with your settings in `database.yml` - you'll need to provide this file's code on here for us to help you fix it!